# Write a path to call a particular servlet.

Tags: forms, servlets, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I need a help with getting right path so that my request from a JSP page to a servlet works fine. Right now its giving me an error Servlet not found .. I am working in eclipse. My directory is like this ::

```
At the top level is my Project_Name 2_8_2012. Now inside JavaResources i have a Src folder inside which i have a package Mypackage inside which i have a TimeServlet.java and TimeManagement.java.
```

my JSP page is in `WebContent/jsp/Page.jsp`

Now from `Page.jsp` i send a request on input submit button click. Basically a form is submitted

```
<form  id="timeform" name="timeformname" action="/2_8_2012/jsp/timeservlet" method="post">
```

which goes to my `web.xml` where i have this code ::

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Timeserv</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>  
            MyPackage.TimeServlet  
        </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Timeserv</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/2_8_2012/jsp/timeservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

but i get the error `servlet not found.`

To open a page.jsp on my browser i go to link

```
http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/Page.jsp.
```

and it opens fine.

How should i give a path so that my servlet is called up ? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

change the URL-PAttern to

/jsp/timeservlet and check